# Retornar Timestamp Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Eu quero converter uma data para um numero, um timestamp. Dentro de um `select` preciso retornar além da data o timestamp dela.

Exemplo de consulta:

```
Select sysdate, TIMESTAMP_DE_SYSDATE from dual
```

**Timestamp**

é uma marca temporal (ou estampa de tempo) que é uma cadeia de caracteres denotando a hora ou data que certo evento ocorreu. A cadeia é geralmente apresentada num formato consistente, permitindo fácil comparação entre duas marcas temporais distintas. No unix existe uma marca temporal importante que define o início da Era Unix, "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", usada como referência no cálculo de tempo dessa plataforma.

Comment: veja se isso responde: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245250/oracle-casting-date-to-timestamp-with-time-zone-with-offset

Comment: pior que não, eu preciso que o retorno seja um inteiro, tipo isso aqui oh: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: gambiarra, mas parece que dá certo :P (no caso você converteria a data em _timestamp_ antes) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26650393/4551469

Comment: kkkk este funcionou, acho que talvez a solução seja isso mesmo, não achei nada melhor. Queria algo que soasse menos verboso e mais intuitivo, mas acho que não tem :),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente não existe uma função nativa no Oracle para obter o Unix datetime a partir de uma data.

A solução seria fazer o cálculo você mesmo, a partir da data do Unix epoch (01/01/1970). Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT sysdate, ((sysdate - TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) * 60 * 60 * 24) FROM dual
```

Comment: Valeu, triste em saber que so tem out de gambi.